# Get unseen messages via IMAP

Tags: email, go, imap

I need to extract some data from new (unseen) messages; I'm trying to make range of that data:

```
c, _ = imap.Dial("someserverr")


defer c.Logout(30 * time.Second)


fmt.Println("Server says hello:", c.Data[0].Info)
c.Data = nil

if c.State() == imap.Login {
    c.Login("somedata", "somedata")
}

c.Select("INBOX", false)

set, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("")
fmt.Println("unseen", c.Mailbox.Unseen)
fmt.Println(c.Mailbox)
if c.Mailbox.Unseen >= 1 {
    set.AddRange(1, c.Mailbox.Unseen)
} else {
    set.Add("0:0")
}
```

The main problem here is command `c.Mailbox` showing wrong number of unseen messages.

For example, if I have 5 unread messages in INBOX it shows 1. If I mark that one as read, it will show 4, and so on.

Comment: ok , so ive made a telnet connect to mail server and looks like info about c.Mailbox.Unseen show only the 1st unseen msg in folder. So now i understand why it work as it work. But  i need to look on all unread msgs, any clue how to do it?

Comment: First, the Go standard library does not have anything to work with IMAP (except for `net/textproto` which is not IMAP-specific), so start with telling us which package are you using. Second, quick googling for `imap+get+all+unread+messages` turns up a ["use search, not status" suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22857102/720999) among gazillions of other links. How about exploring that idea?

Comment: iam using `"github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap"` and looks like i found what i need with `imap.LabelFilter("UNSEEN")` em i right that it show amount of unread mails?

Comment: No idea, but fro what I read while reseaching on your question the answer appears to be "yes". Do try yourself, really.